# I need code to validate any time in c# in HHMMSS format

Tags: c#, validation, time

Please help me to find code to  validate any time in c#.
format- HHMMSS

Comment: Oh yes, this smells like a homework.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is probably to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
DateTime time;
bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(text,
                                    "HHmmss",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.None,
                                    out time);
```

Note that "M" is months whereas "m" is minutes, and "s" is seconds; "HH" is hours in the 24 hour clock instead of "hh" which would use the 12 hour clock (usually with the am/pm indicator elsewhere).

The `DateTimeStyles.None` says to use the default options. That will use todays' date as the date to go with the time. You could specify `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` which would use January 1st 1AD instead.

If `valid` is false, `time` will be set to `DateTime.MinValue`.

---

Another alternative if you're using .NET 4 is to use [`TimeSpan.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
TimeSpan time;
bool valid = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(text,
                                    "hhmmss",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    out time);
```

Note the use of "hh" instead of "HH" this time. See the [Custom TimeSpan format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) page on MSDN for more information - but remember this is only available in .NET 4.

Comment: You have the 3rd and 4th parameter swapped.

Comment: yeah, this method really needs an overload without *either* of those.  They're probably concerned about choosing a default `IFormatProvider` due to localization, but you can already use `null` (which uses the current culture).

Comment: @Matthew: Yup. Personally I wish that it would default to the invariant culture (so that code which didn't explicitly talk about cultures would work the same everywhere), but there we go.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

```
static bool IsTimeValid(string time)
{
  DateTime dt;

  return DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "HHmmss", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
}
```