# how to perform c# time validation in HHMMSS format

Tags: c#, validation, time

Output of this code will always be false,even if I pass date in  correct format.Please help me...
Here the 2 Parameters passed are time and format, ie("HHMMSS" format).

```
    static bool ValidateTime(string time, string format)
    {
        try
        {
            //time = time.Replace(":","");
            System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo tinfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();

            tinfo.LongTimePattern = format;

            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "format", tinfo);
            if (dt.Hour != null)
            {

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710455/i-need-code-to-validate-any-time-in-c-in-hhmmss-format

Comment: "MM" in a format string will format **months** - not minutes. It's case sensitive - use "mm" for minutes

Comment: Why don't you accept the solution ? It'll easy for others to find out solution quickly.

Answer (score 11):

```
static bool ValidateTime(string time, string format)
{
    DateTime outTime;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(time, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outTime);
}
```

Remember that you should use "HHmmss" format string to validate 24-hour time.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The following code works. You'll have to tweak a bit and add the method signatures.

```
string time = "201555";
string format = "HHmmss";
bool ok = false;

try
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, format, provider);
    if (dt.Hour != null)
    {
        ok = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //// ok = false; // already setup in initializer above.
}
```