# Determine if a string of format "hh:mm" is valid date

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I'm taking an Udemy course. There is this exercise:

> Given an user input of the following form hh:mm, determine it's a valid date.
> 19:20 or 01:20 are valid inputs, but 24:01 is not.

I implemented it by working on chars but I believe I'm complicating myself. Is there an alternative(besides regex) ? (maybe using some .net builtins(DateTime/Timespan)

```
        Console.Write("Enter a time value(ex: 19:20): ");
        var result = "Valid time";
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid time");
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        var dates = input.Split(":");

        //validate hour
        var firstDigitHour = (int)char.GetNumericValue(dates[0][0]);
        var secondDigitHour = (int)char.GetNumericValue(dates[0][1]);
        var hour = 10 * firstDigitHour + secondDigitHour;
        if (hour > 23) {
            result = "Invalid time";
        }

        //validate minutes
        var firstDigitMinute = (int)char.GetNumericValue(dates[1][0]);
        var secondDigitMinute = (int)char.GetNumericValue(dates[1][1]);
        var minutes = 10 * firstDigitMinute + secondDigitMinute;
        if (minutes > 59 ) {
            result = "Invalid time";
        }


        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: There are many easier ways but it depends what the course is trying to teach you, and parsing the hard way has learning benefits. You need to consider that there might not be a ':', lengths might not be as expected, and there might be non-digits. E.g. 0930, 9:30, ab:cd, 09:3, empty, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to perform c# time validation in HHMMSS format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710501/how-to-perform-c-sharp-time-validation-in-hhmmss-format) (Automatic duplication detection comment - you can easily adjust that question to not allow seconds)

Comment: yes, indeed the question seems duplicate to the one above mentioned by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public static bool IsValidTimeFormat(string input)
{
    TimeSpan dummyOutput;
    return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
}
```

And try out:

```
string yourString = "19:20";
string yourString2 = "24:48";
Console.WriteLine(IsValidTimeFormat(yourString).ToString()); //will print True
Console.WriteLine(IsValidTimeFormat(yourString2).ToString()); //will print False
```

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest using [`DateTime.TryParseExact()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0) by providing the time format pattern to validate the time string is a valid `DateTime`.

```cs
bool isValidTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime time);
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BgZhxf)